# Scala: Producing the intermediate results of a fold

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I've come across the problem of maintaining a state throughout a map operation several times. Imagine the following task:

Given a List[Int], map each element to the sum of all preceding elements and itself.
So 1,2,3 becomes 1, 1+2, 1+2+3.

One solution I've come up with is:

```
scala> val a = 1 to 5                                                
a: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive with scala.collection.immutable.Range.ByOne = Range(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> a.foldLeft(List(0)){ case (l,i) => (l.head + i) :: l }.reverse
res3: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15)
```

But somehow I feel that there has to be a simpler solution.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You're trying to compute the sequence of **partial sums**.

The general operation for computing such accumulations is not `fold` but [`scan`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum), though `scan` is expressible through `fold` in the way you showed (and `fold` is actually the last element of the list produced by `scan`).

```
scala> List(1,2,3).scanLeft(0)(_ + _)
res26: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 3, 6)
```

Comment: Indeed, there is a scanLeft function, which does exactly what I need. If you or someone else will add a valid scala example of its usage, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Edited the answer with some example I found. Using nicer syntax, `a scanLeft(0) { (a, b) => a + b }` might stil work though

Comment: scala> List(1,2,3).scanLeft(0)(\_+\_)

Comment: Funny enough, following your link, it says "the following example is from SO".

Answer (score 9):

@Dario gave the answer, but just to add that the scala library provides scanLeft:

```
scala> List(1,2,3).scanLeft(0)(_ + _)
res26: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 3, 6)
```

Answer (score 7):

The `scan` answers are the best ones, but it's worth noting that one can make the fold look nicer and/or be shorter than in your question.  First, you don't need to use pattern matching:

```
a.foldLeft(List(0)){ (l,i) => (l.head + i) :: l }.reverse
```

Second, note that foldLeft has an abbreviation:

```
(List(0) /: a){ (l,i) => (l.head + i) :: l }.reverse
```

Third, note that you can, if you want, use a collection that can append efficiently so that you don't need to reverse:

```
(Vector(0) /: a){ (v,i) => v :+ (v.last + i) }
```

So while this isn't nearly as compact as `scanLeft`:

```
a.scanLeft(0)(_ + _)
```

it's still not too bad.

Comment: This is useful when your binary op's type is not (B, B) => B, but (C, B) => C

Answer (score 6):

I like to fold around just like everybody else, but a less FP answer is very concise and readable:

```
 a.map{var v=0; x=>{v+=x; v}}
```

Comment: Nitpicking, but I wonder if the order is guaranteed when `map` calls its parameter function.

Comment: @HRJ - It is guaranteed for serial collections.  It is not guaranteed for parallel collections, but then you have worse problems (not synchronized on `v`).